# Html comment in the jsp not visible on client

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am new to jsp. Today I was reading about html comments in the jsp should be printed on the page as it is. But I am unable to see it. May be someone can help me with that. He is my small jsp page code.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Commentsin JSP </h1>

       <%-- Trying single line comment --%>
       <!-- 
          -Trying Multline
          -Comments
        -->
       <!--  Hello -->

      <% String var = "1";   %>
      Var is== <%=var %> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I can see Var is== 1 is printed on the generated page but I was expecting a Hello first but its not there. I dont understand what am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: What's your stack? Which application server are you using? Is it fronted by a web server like Apache?

Comment: yes I m using tomcat

Comment: With or without Apache?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not there"? jsp comments should not make it to the client. Html comments go to the client but are not visible.

Comment: @Andres OP is referring to HTML comments. The file contains both types.

Comment: @Jeena Just to make sure, because it's not apparent from your question: you know that HTML comments are not rendered by the browser, right? You can only see them by viewing the HTML source.

Comment: Yes it is with Apache.

Comment: Is the Apache web server configured to use mod_deflate, mod_pagespeed, or another module that might be stripping off the comments?

Comment: @Robby so it means it will not be printed on the page displayed? I am quite new to web development.  Acc to my understanding <!-- comments ... -->
These comments are treated as uninterpreted template text by the JSP container. So I thought I will see them on the generated page. But may be i am wrong.

Comment: In your browser, right-click in your page and select **View source** or **View page source**. Check for the presence of comments there.

Comment: I have not changed any settings on Apache. They all have the default values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133608/discussion-between-jeena-and-robby-cornelissen).

Comment: In that kind of question, it could be interesting to show the source code AND the client output code (before and after the jsp compilation).